# Clone elements and add into mark-up code so form submission picks them up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the clone button is clicked, size and length fields should be cloned and placed below. **Crucial point is**, I should be able to see these cloned mark-up code when I check the browser source code because I'll submit all fields.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<style>
    div { display:inline-block; }
    .needles, .yarns, .options { border:1px solid #14A; padding:10px; }
</style>

<div class='needles'>
    <p>NEEDLES</p>
    <div class='options'>
        <div class='label'>Size</div>
        <div class='field'>
            <input id='size-0' name='size-0' value='Size' />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class='options'>
        <div class='label'>Length</div>
        <div class='field'>
            <input id='length-0' name='length-0' value='Length' />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <button>Clone</button>
</div>

<br />

<div class='yarns'>
    <p>YARNS</p>
    <div class='options'>
        <div class='label'>Size</div>
        <div class='field'>
            <input id='size-0' name='size-0' value='Size' />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class='options'>
        <div class='label'>Length</div>
        <div class='field'>
            <input id='length-0' name='length-0' value='Length' />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <button>Clone</button>
</div>
```

I did something like this but I think it is a mess to be honest.

```
 $("button").click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();

     var $parent = $(this).closest('div');
     var $length = $parent.prev();
     var $size = $length.prev();

     var size = $size.clone(false).wrap('<p>').parent().html();
     var length = $length.clone(false).wrap('<p>').parent().html();

     var spanId = $(size).children('span').attr('id');
     var idArray = spanId.split("__");
     var currentIdentifierNo = idArray[idArray.length-2];
     var newIdentifierNo = parseInt(currentIdentifierNo)+1;
     var currentIdentifier = '__' + currentIdentifierNo + '__';
     var newIdentifier = '__' + newIdentifierNo + '__';

     var re = new RegExp(currentIdentifier, 'g');
     size = size.replace(re, newIdentifier);
     length = length.replace(re, newIdentifier);

     var html = size + length;
     $(this).before(html);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `name` attribute for this to work:

```
length.find('input').attr('name', 'length-1');
size.find('input').attr('name', 'size-1');
```

If you send the same key / value pairs in the form, the server doesn't know which is which.

Comment: I need the full jquery code. I have very very limited knowledge about jquery. It sound like 'do it for me' but unfortunately I can't even turn what I'am told into code.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't write it for you. The basic idea is to end up with `length-0, length-1, size-0, size-1` in your form.